# How to introduce fonts in AppAsset in Yii2?

Tags: fonts, yii2

I want to add my desired font in Yii2. But alterations do not apply.  This is my code:

**web/css/my.css**:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Font';
src: url("../fonts/fonts/woff2") format('truetype');
src: url("../fonts/fonts/woff") format('truetype');
src: url("../fonts/fonts/ttf") format('truetype');
src: url("../fonts/fonts/eot") format('truetype');
}

body {
font-family: "Font"
}
```

**AppAsset**:

```
 public $css = [
    'css/my.css',
    'fonts/fonts',

];
```

I think the problem is the introduction of fonts in AppAsset. What is should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this code and it is working.

AppAsset.php

```
public $css = [
      'css/site.css',
      'css/fonts.css?family=PT+Sans:400,700'
];
```

fonts.css

```
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'PT Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('PT Sans'), local('PTSans-Regular'), url('../fonts/JX7MlXqjSJNjQvI4heMMGvY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.woff2') format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
```

Comment: how to add eot,woff, woff2 to AppAsset? I added :                                   public $css = [
        'css/app.css',
        'fonts/font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        'fonts/fonts', // here my fonts
    ];   I introduce fonts in app.css, but dose not change in browser?

Comment: you should include fonts in app.css

Comment: I added font.css  to AppAsset (I had forgotten). thanks

Answer (score 1):

CSS looks for fonts in the specified files. You dont need to load them through asset. Check if you have proper permissions on you files and if they exist in proper directory. And you should set font as such:

```
body {
   font-family: "Font"
}
```